# Is it possible to explicitly write down a codomain or the range of this 'sequence'?

Tags: sequences-and-series, definition

I came up with questions like the following when reading people discussing the definition of a sequence on freenode IRC ##math channel.

Consider a 'sequence' defined by $f_0=\emptyset$ and $f_1=\{f_0\}=\{\emptyset\}$ and $f_{n+1}=\{f_0,...,f_n\}$ for all n $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$.

Since a sequence is formally defined/considered to be a function, there exist a codomain and the range of $f$.

**Question:** Is it possible to explicitly write down a set that is a codomain of $f$ or even is the range of $f$ ?

Comment: Axiom of infinity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *sequence* $\left(f_n\right)_{n\geq 0}$  is precisely the *[recursive definition of the natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#von_Neumann_construction)* by John von Neumann.

> **John von Neumann (1923):** The embedding of the natural numbers within set theory is
>   \begin{align*}
> 0:=\emptyset\qquad\qquad n+1:=n\cup\{n\}
> \end{align*}

$$ $$

> We obtain according to this definition
>   \begin{align*}
> 0= f_0&=\emptyset\\
> 1=f_1&=\{0\}\\
> &=\{\emptyset\}\\
> 2=f_2&=\{0,1\}\\
> &=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\\
> 3=f_3&=\{0,1,2\}\\
> &=\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}\\
> 4=f_4&=\{0,1,2,3\}\\
> &=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\},\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}\}\\
> &\cdots
> \end{align*}
>
> So, we can conclude: The image (range) of $f$ can be identified with the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$. The codomain of $f$ is any set containing $\mathbb{N}$.